# How to avoid filtering when page loads first time. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In this code user can filter the products by selecting subcategory and brands from select list.

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select ng-init="SelectedSubCategory = SubCategories[0]" ng-model="SelectedSubCategory" ng-options="x as x.name for x in SubCategories | orderBy:'name'" class='form-control'>
                <option value="" ng-selected="selected">Select Sub Category</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td>

            <select ng-init="SelectedBarnd = Brands[0]" ng-model="SelectedBrand" ng-options="x as x.name for x in Brands | orderBy:'name'" class='form-control'>
                <option value="" ng-selected="selected">Select Brand</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>SUB Category</th>
        <th>Image Path</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in Products | filter: {'SubCategoryID':SelectedSubCategory.id}:true | filter: {'BrandID':SelectedBrand.id}:true ">
        <td>{{ product.ProductID }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.BrandName }} {{ product.ProductName }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.SubCategoryName }}</td>
        <td> <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.ProductImagePath }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But when page initially loads, "Select Sub Category" and "select Brand" is displaying to user in select-List. But no products is displaying. all products got filtered.

Basically i want initially no products is filtered, but when user select a sub category and/or brand then only filter should apply.

What code changes i need to do for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ng-init="SelectedBarnd = Brands[0]"` and `ng-init="SelectedSubCategory = SubCategories[0]"` to not initially filter the products when the page loads.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.Brands = [
    {name: 'Bob', id: 0},
    {name: 'Chris', id: 1},
    {name: 'Dennis', id: 2}
  ];
  $scope.SubCategories = [
    {name: 'A', id: 0},
    {name: 'B', id: 1},
    {name: 'C', id: 2}
  ];
  
  $scope.Products = [
    {ProductID: 0, BrandID: 0, BrandName: 'Bob', SubCategoryID: 0, SubCategoryName: 'A'},
    {ProductID: 1, BrandID: 0, BrandName: 'Bob', SubCategoryID: 1, SubCategoryName: 'B'},
    {ProductID: 2, BrandID: 0, BrandName: 'Bob', SubCategoryID: 2, SubCategoryName: 'C'},
    {ProductID: 3, BrandID: 1, BrandName: 'Chris', SubCategoryID: 0, SubCategoryName: 'A'},
    {ProductID: 4, BrandID: 1, BrandName: 'Chris', SubCategoryID: 1, SubCategoryName: 'B'},
    {ProductID: 5, BrandID: 1, BrandName: 'Chris', SubCategoryID: 2, SubCategoryName: 'C'},    
    {ProductID: 6, BrandID: 2, BrandName: 'Dennis', SubCategoryID: 0, SubCategoryName: 'A'},
    {ProductID: 7, BrandID: 2, BrandName: 'Dennis', SubCategoryID: 1, SubCategoryName: 'B'},
    {ProductID: 8, BrandID: 2, BrandName: 'Dennis', SubCategoryID: 2, SubCategoryName: 'C'},
    {}
  ];
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>

  <table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="SelectedSubCategory" ng-options="x as x.name for x in SubCategories | orderBy:'name'" class='form-control'>
          <option value="" ng-selected="selected">Select Sub Category</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>

        <select ng-model="SelectedBrand" ng-options="x as x.name for x in Brands | orderBy:'name'" class='form-control'>
          <option value="" ng-selected="selected">Select Brand</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>SUB Category</th>
      <th>Image Path</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in Products | filter: {'SubCategoryID':SelectedSubCategory.id}:true | filter: {'BrandID':SelectedBrand.id}:true ">
      <td>{{ product.ProductID }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.BrandName }} {{ product.ProductName }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.SubCategoryName }}</td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.ProductImagePath }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directive and put whatever condition you like in there.

Answer (score 0):

The directives `ng-show` and `ng-hide` will help you make any view element visible or invisible. They change the display property dinamically and also apply some CSS classes in order to do some animations or any other logics.

Those show or hide according to a statement, value or logical statement given. All those should taken from `$scope`.

For values, apart from booleans, any number > 0, or anything distinct from null or undefined will be evaluated as `true`.

For example, in the table below, if `category` and `subcategory` both are not set, table won't render. This will be useful if at page load, those are actually unset.

```
<table class='table table-bordered' ng-show="category && subcategory">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>SUB Category</th>
        <th>Image Path</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in Products | filter: {'SubCategoryID':SelectedSubCategory.id}:true | filter: {'BrandID':SelectedBrand.id}:true ">
        <td>{{ product.ProductID }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.BrandName }} {{ product.ProductName }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.SubCategoryName }}</td>
        <td> <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.ProductImagePath }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Very important: don't combine both `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

There's also `ng-if` which not only makes it invisible, but drops off or in any view element.